# Plotting second and third column of matrix and using first column as values for the x axis using ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix:

```
a<-c(0.863950263765782, 0.908204672069546, 0.931564826815488, 0.947460752561418, 0.959463328487368, 0.969060077042643, 0.977026409365163, 0.983818665594281,0.989719993426693)

b<-c(0.787029935566084, 0.872407618393809, 0.925762651962245, 0.948331740835959, 0.961947304263652, 0.971489926009247, 0.978878398154957, 0.984799730999978, 0.9899910908)

c<-c("0.1-0.9", "0.2-0.9", "0.3-0.9", "0.4-0.9", "0.5-0.9", "0.6-0.9", "0.7-0.9", "0.8-0.9", "0.9")

e<-cbind(c,a,b)
```

I would like to plot `e[,2]` and `e[,3]` on the same graph and use the corresponding entries in `e[,1]` as the values of the x-axis.

How can this be done using `ggplot` or `plot()` ?

1. I tried `melt(e, id.vars=1:1)` but I couldn't get the variables in the right format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
e <- melt(as.data.frame(e), id.vars="c",  measure.vars=c("a", "b"), variable.name="var", value.name="val")
ggplot(e, aes(x=c, y=val, colour=var)) + geom_point()
```

**Edit:**

Strange. This code ...

```
a<-c("0.863950263765782", "0.908204672069546", "0.931564826815488", "0.947460752561418", "0.959463328487368", "0.969060077042643", "0.977026409365163", "0.983818665594281","0.989719993426693")
b<-c("0.787029935566084", "0.872407618393809", "0.925762651962245", "0.948331740835959", "0.961947304263652", "0.971489926009247", "0.978878398154957", "0.984799730999978", "0.9899910908")
c<-c("0.1-0.9", "0.2-0.9", "0.3-0.9", "0.4-0.9", "0.5-0.9", "0.6-0.9", "0.7-0.9", "0.8-0.9", "0.9")
e<-cbind(c,a,b)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
e <- melt(as.data.frame(e), id.vars="c",  measure.vars=c("a", "b"), variable.name="var", value.name="val")
ggplot(e, aes(x=c, y=val, colour=var)) + 
  geom_point()
```

... leads to this output on my machine:

[image]

And this

```
ggplot(e, aes(x=c, y=as.numeric(val), colour=var, group=var)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

... leads to this:

[image]

Comment: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'val' not found
>

Comment: I changed val to value and var to variable but still the plot doesn't really do what it is supposed to

Comment: @user1723765 plots the numerics on y and the labels on x as it - I guess - is supposed to do, here.

Comment: if I simply plot a and b using plot(a), lines(b), this is what I get: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/plot.pdf what's causing the difference?

Comment: @user1723765 You get this with `ggplot` using e.g. `ggplot(e, aes(x=c, y=as.numeric(val), colour=var, group=var)) + geom_point() + geom_line()`

Comment: so when I copy paste your code I get: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'val' not found

Comment: You also did `e <- melt(as.data.frame(e), id.vars="c",  measure.vars=c("a", "b"), variable.name="var", value.name="val")
` before?

Comment: ok I closed R and tried it again, there was probably some issue with variables stored in the working space. thanks